# Xcode Server OTA Install - "Cannot Connect to Server"

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, enterprise, ota, xcode-server

We have just started using Xcode Server for continuous integration.

Various developers and testers on our team are receiving the message "Cannot connect to server" when tapping the "Install" button from the Xcode Server integration page. It happens only on a specific bot, and only on iPad devices.

We are uploading an Enterprise build and have followed the steps in the following article to make sure the Enterprise certificate is accessible.
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/ios-continous-integration-for-enterprise